# Code fails to download a file more than once

Tags: c#, download, webclient

Whenever I click a button in my GUI this code gets executed

```
this.file_name = @"c:\temp\file_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks / 10000 +".pdf";

client.DownloadFileCompleted +=
                    new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(pdfDownloadComplete);

client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(uri), file_name);
```

It's supposed to download a pdf file. It works fine the first time I click it, but the second time all it does is it creates an empty file in the temp directory and downloads nothing, I click the same button afterwards nothing new happens.

I cannot figure it out why it won't download more than once.

**Later Edit**

This is the complete code which is needed http://pastie.org/private/y7na2f4fjdu6anzteoa

I noticed that if I remove the download that checks for content type, the app downloads files without a problem

```
client.HeadOnly = true;
byte[] body = client.DownloadData(uri); // note should be 0-length
string type = client.ResponseHeaders["content-type"];
client.HeadOnly = false;
```

Still, I need to know if I'm getting text of a file from that URL so I need to make that call.

Comment: Of what type is `client`? What does `pdfDownloadComplete` do?

Comment: I have added some more code so things are a bit clearer. pdfDownloadComplete is an empty function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has at least one issue that might be root of the problem:
You do an async download inside a `using` block. I don't really know what happens if the download is still running when the scope of the using block is left, but I guess that it is canceled. You should avoid that problem by using `DownloadFile` instead of `DownloadFileAsync`.
Additionally, please check whether it works, when you use the normal `WebClient` class and not your `MyClient` class.

Comment: I tried using both `DownloadFile` and `DownloadFileAsync` they both give the same result. I use the `MyClient` class for getting the content type of the content found at URL, so I know I get a file or a text (in case of an error).